# How can I connect a Facebook app with an existing Facebook page?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have a Facebook fan page (created late 2011) for one of my apps.  I'm in the process of adding Facebook SDK support to the app to allow users to post photos to their news feeds.

What I want to do is connect the FACEBOOK APP with the existing FACEBOOK PAGE.

I'd assume you could go into the Facebook Page settings and LINK THE APPID TO THE PAGE.  But I can't seem to find anything.  I had a look in the app settings too, and that has Canvas pages, Page Tabs, but nothing quite looks right.

**All I want to actually do** is let my users post photos to their newsfeeds from my app.  And those photos then link to the Enscripted fan page.  So if I'm missing something, let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I link existing facebook page to a facebook app](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10773915/can-i-link-existing-facebook-page-to-a-facebook-app)

Answer (score 0):

To add an app to a Facebook Page, you need to add a Page Tab to your page. This document will help you with that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/